# Placing pins on a map fragment in a fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I cannot add markers to my map using the recommended documentation, I have no errors however markers are not appearing on the map.

I have tried the following:

```java
    gmap = googleMap;
    gmap.setMinZoomPreference(12);
       LatLng ny = new LatLng(40.7143528, -74.0059731);
        gmap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ny));
```

and

```java
    gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(10, 10))
                .title("Hello world"));
```

Neither of these are working.

Here is my main activity,

```java
private static MapView mapView;
private GoogleMap gmap;
private static final String MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY = "MapViewBundleKey";

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    session = new SessionHandler(getApplicationContext());
    final User user = session.getUserDetails();

    final View background = findViewById(R.id.home_background_view);
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.home_view_pager);
    MainPagerAdapter adapter = new MainPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    final int colourGreen = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.Green);
    final int colourPink = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.Pink);
    final int colourBlue = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.CafeSeaBlue);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.am_tab_layout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    loadLocations();


//        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
//                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
//        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);



    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        //mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                //if on first screen
            if (position == 0)
            {
                background.setBackgroundColor(colourBlue);
                    //background.setAlpha(1-positionOffset);
            }

                //if on mid screen
            else if (position == 1) {
                background.setBackgroundColor(colourPink);
                    //background.setAlpha(positionOffset);
            }

                //if on last screen
            else if (position == 2) {
                background.setBackgroundColor(colourGreen);
                    //background.setAlpha(1+positionOffset);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if(position == 0)
            {

            }if(position == 2){

    //                        gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    //                                .position(new LatLng(50, 50))
    //                                .title("Hello world"));

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();


}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

    globalLat = location.getLatitude();
    globalLong = location.getLongitude();

    Log.d("Location","Longitude = "+currentLongitude);
    Log.d("Location","Latitude = "+currentLatitude);



    if(tv1 != null)
        tv1.setText(Double.toString(currentLatitude));


    if(tv2 != null)
        tv2.setText(Double.toString(currentLongitude));

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
    //progress bar
private void displayLoader() {
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading.. Please wait...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + adapter.getItem(position) + " on row number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    Bundle mapViewBundle = outState.getBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
    if (mapViewBundle == null) {
        mapViewBundle = new Bundle();
        outState.putBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY, mapViewBundle);
    }

}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10, 10))
        .title("Hello world"));
}
}
```

And my layout:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
tools:background="@color/CafeSeaBlue"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<View
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
android:background="@drawable/card_background" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
android:id="@+id/latText1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="32dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/longText"
android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
android:background="@color/White"
android:text="Map Screen"
android:textAlignment="center"/>


<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
tools:context=".HomeActivity"
/>

</FrameLayout>
```

`//        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
//                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
//        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);`

having this uncommented in the section it is currently in crashes it unexpectedly, saying null object reference

The map itself loads however I cannot get pins on it. I have tried so many methods and probably have quite a bit of unnecessary code.

The map displays on the screen, i would attach an image but i require 10 points before I am able to. I cannot add markers to my map using the recommended documentation, I have no errors however markers are not appearing on the map.

I have tried the following:

```java
    gmap = googleMap;
    gmap.setMinZoomPreference(12);
       LatLng ny = new LatLng(40.7143528, -74.0059731);
        gmap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ny));
```

and

```java
    gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(10, 10))
                .title("Hello world"));
```

Neither of these are working.

Here is my main activity,

```java
private static MapView mapView;
private GoogleMap gmap;
private static final String MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY = "MapViewBundleKey";

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    session = new SessionHandler(getApplicationContext());
    final User user = session.getUserDetails();

    final View background = findViewById(R.id.home_background_view);
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.home_view_pager);
    MainPagerAdapter adapter = new MainPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    final int colourGreen = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.Green);
    final int colourPink = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.Pink);
    final int colourBlue = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.CafeSeaBlue);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.am_tab_layout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    loadLocations();


//        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
//                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
//        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);



    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        //mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                //if on first screen
            if (position == 0)
            {
                background.setBackgroundColor(colourBlue);
                    //background.setAlpha(1-positionOffset);
            }

                //if on mid screen
            else if (position == 1) {
                background.setBackgroundColor(colourPink);
                    //background.setAlpha(positionOffset);
            }

                //if on last screen
            else if (position == 2) {
                background.setBackgroundColor(colourGreen);
                    //background.setAlpha(1+positionOffset);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if(position == 0)
            {

            }if(position == 2){

    //                        gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    //                                .position(new LatLng(50, 50))
    //                                .title("Hello world"));

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();


}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

    globalLat = location.getLatitude();
    globalLong = location.getLongitude();

    Log.d("Location","Longitude = "+currentLongitude);
    Log.d("Location","Latitude = "+currentLatitude);



    if(tv1 != null)
        tv1.setText(Double.toString(currentLatitude));


    if(tv2 != null)
        tv2.setText(Double.toString(currentLongitude));

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
    //progress bar
private void displayLoader() {
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading.. Please wait...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + adapter.getItem(position) + " on row number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    Bundle mapViewBundle = outState.getBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
    if (mapViewBundle == null) {
        mapViewBundle = new Bundle();
        outState.putBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY, mapViewBundle);
    }

}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10, 10))
        .title("Hello world"));
}
}
```

And my layout:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
tools:background="@color/CafeSeaBlue"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<View
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
android:background="@drawable/card_background" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
android:id="@+id/latText1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="32dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/longText"
android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
android:background="@color/White"
android:text="Map Screen"
android:textAlignment="center"/>


<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
tools:context=".HomeActivity"
/>

</FrameLayout>
```

`//        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
//                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
//        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);`

having this uncommented in the section it is currently in crashes it unexpectedly, saying null object reference

The map itself loads however I cannot get pins on it. I have tried so many methods and probably have quite a bit of unnecessary code.

I would attach an image of the displaying and interatable map here but I do not have 10 points.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm0nZ.png

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are focusing your map on the NY City area, but are pinning your marker in the middle of Nigeria.  Are you sure that the marker is not successfully added?  Try setting your marker near where you position the map focus.

Comment: No i have tried moving the map around however I cannot see any marker

Answer (score 0):

```
mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

these codes are necessary, else you won't get any callback to 
`onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {}`

I think the crash occurs because the variable **gmap** is not initialised. Just add **gmap = map** before adding the marker in the **onMapReady**.

Comment: is gmap not initialised on the second line?

Comment: Also I am unsure of where you are suggesting that i put this code

Comment: you only created a variable gmap in the second line. so just put the gmap=map in your onMapReady() override method and uncomment those code block. your code should be working fine.